# Eventlistener-alert in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to alert "Hello" when clicking on a div with the ID `navBtnContainer`. This event listener should work for but at first it always says `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).stop is not a function` and if I remove the `.stop()` it does not work either:

```
$('#navBtnContainer').stop().on('click', function() {
    alert("Hello");
});
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and include a working example of the issue?  You can hit Ctrl+M to brin up the on site code editor.  I've tried this logic without the stop and it works fine.  What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Can you please tell me if this fiddle helps https://jsfiddle.net/kblau237/bodu7242/